# Issue on keeping Dropdown Slide Down Until Mouse is Over of Child Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can force the `.droper` to be slide down until the mouse is still over all child `<li>` s?

As you can see from the demo the `.droper` starts to slide up as soon as the mouse is out of the `.menu-itemb` (which make sence to me!) but I need to keep it available until user is browsing on the dropdown menu

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu-itemb").mouseover(function(){
  
   $(".droper").stop().slideDown("slow");
  });
  $(".menu-itemb").mouseout(function(){
   $(".droper").slideUp("slow");
  });
 });
```

```css
body {
  background: #1f1f1f;
}

.site-navigation {
 display: block;
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 40px;
}

.site-navigation ul {
  background: #3498DB;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}

.site-navigation li {
 color: #fff;
  background: #3498DB;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 2px 0 0;
 padding: 12px;
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
  
.site-navigation li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.site-navigation li:hover {
 @include transition(background, 0.2s);
 background: #52a6df;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.site-navigation ul li ul {
 background: #52a6df;
 display:none;
 float: left;
  min-width: 150px;
 position: absolute;
  transition: visibility 0.65s ease-in;
  margin-top:12px;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 999;
}

.site-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
.site-navigation ul li ul:hover {
   visibility: visible;
}

.site-navigation ul li ul li {
 clear: both;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
  width: 100%;
}

.site-navigation ul li ul li:hover {
 background: #74b7e4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="navigation" class="site-navigation" role="navigation">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li class="menu-itemb"><a href="#">Snippets</a>
      <ul class="droper">
        <li class="menu-item sub-menu"><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item sub-menu"><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item sub-menu"><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item sub-menu"><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item sub-menu"><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one `.stop()` before the slideUp. Without it, the animation will be triggered and executed to the end when you move the mouse between the items...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu-itemb").mouseover(function(){
  
   $(".droper").stop().slideDown("slow");
  });
  $(".menu-itemb").mouseout(function(){
   $(".droper").stop().slideUp("slow");
  });
 });
```

```css
body {
  background: #1f1f1f;
}

.site-navigation {
 display: block;
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 40px;
}

.site-navigation ul {
  background: #3498DB;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}

.site-navigation li {
 color: #fff;
  background: #3498DB;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 2px 0 0;
 padding: 12px;
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
  
.site-navigation li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.site-navigation li:hover {
 @include transition(background, 0.2s);
 background: #52a6df;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.site-navigation ul li ul {
 background: #52a6df;
 display:none;
 float: left;
  min-width: 150px;
 position: absolute;
  transition: visibility 0.65s ease-in;
  margin-top:12px;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 999;
}

.site-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
.site-navigation ul li ul:hover {
   visibility: visible;
}

.site-navigation ul li ul li {
 clear: both;
 padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
  width: 100%;
}

.site-navigation ul li ul li:hover {
 background: #74b7e4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="navigation" class="site-navigation" role="navigation">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li class="menu-itemb"><a href="#">Snippets</a>
      <ul class="droper">
        <li class="menu-item sub-menu"><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item sub-menu"><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item sub-menu"><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item sub-menu"><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item sub-menu"><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks LcSalazar, but can you please let me know what exactly the `stop()` is doing here?

Comment: The `.stop()` function kills any animation that is been executed at the moment with the targeted object. Without it, the previous animation will be completed before another one starts.

Comment: Your code was working, but at the moment that you move the mouse, and hover over the child elements, it was quickly triggering the `.mouseout()` function. Since you didn't have the `.stop()`, the slide up was executed.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix what your problems.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3zrydhn/1/)

```
$(".menu-itemb").on('mouseenter', function () {
$(".droper").stop().slideDown("200");
});
$(".menu-itemb").on('mouseleave', function () {
$(".droper").stop().slideUp("200");
});
```